# Junit test not running testwatcher methods in scalatest

Tags: junit, scalatest

I have few classes of junit tests that I wanna use the testwatcher class with like so

```
 class A extends C {
    @Test
    def testA = {
    //tests
    }
}
```

class B

```
class B extends C{
@Test
def testB ={
//tests
}
}
```

Class C is below

```
trait C extends TestWatcher {
  override def failed(er:Throwable, des:Description) {
      val writer = new FileWriter(new File("D:\\test_"+des.getMethodName+".txt" ))
         writer.write("false")
         writer.close()
 }

  override def succeeded(des:Description) {
     val writer = new FileWriter(new File("D:\\test_"+des.getMethodName+".txt" ))
         writer.write("true")
         writer.close()
 }
}
```

It seems that when I run the tests, the succeeded and fail methods in C are never ran and the files are never created.

I have also tried using @RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner]) but that doesn't work either

Any ideas?